# What are the differences between YUI2.7 and YUI2.8?

Tags: yui

I have encountered a peculiar problem when I migrated from YUI2.7 to YUI2.8 in one of the application I have developed.

I am getting a JSON object from a WebServer and processing that object and creating an array. I am passing that array to a datasource which intern used to create a Datatable.

This mechanism is working fine in YUI2.7 but some exception is being thrown while creating Datatable in YUI2.8. What might be the problem? Is there any specific change in YUI2.8 which is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a list of changes between 2.7 and 2.8 at http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/wiki/ReadMe/Rollup_2.8.0 . for a full change history of each component, you have to look at each component's README file. here are the ones for [datasource](http://github.com/yui/yui2/blob/master/src/datasource/README) and [datatable](http://github.com/yui/yui2/blob/master/src/datatable/README). a full commit history of yui2 is [here](http://github.com/yui/yui2/commits/master/).